# DBI + ruby-odbc fails with Bundler involved

Tags: ruby, odbc, unixodbc, exasolution

I'm connecting to Exasol using the `dbi` and `ruby-odbc` gems with unixodbc and it works fine, loaded like this:

```
require 'dbi'
require 'odbc_utf8'
```

When I add Bundler to the mix, ruby-odbc doesn't seem to be able to find the odbc configuration:

```
Could not load driver (undefined method `driver_name' for ODBC:Module)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:318:in `rescue in load_driver'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242:in `load_driver'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160:in `_get_full_driver'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145:in `connect'
```

It doesn't matter if I require it via `Bundler.require` (with `gem 'ruby-odbc', require: 'odbc_utf8'` in the Gemfile) or with `require 'bundler/setup'` and `require 'odbc_utf8'`.

This is how I try to connect:

```
DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:exa', config['username'], config['password'])
```

In case it matters, this is what my `.odbc.ini` looks like:

```
[exa]
Driver = /opt/EXASolution_ODBC-4.0.8/lib32/libexaodbc-uo22.so
EXAHOST = 192.168.235.84..86:8563
```

**edit**: The way it works without Bundler only does so with Ruby 1.9.3. It looks to me like a scoping issue, as `driver_name` is a variable passed as an argument to the method that raises the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install: gem install dbd-odbc